# How can I use a custom filter with horizontally scrollable bootstrap DataTable?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I am using the horizontal scrollable bootstrap data tables and created a custom filter.

When I select a specific value of my select box, I want to show only columns with that specific class. It is all working well, my only problem is:

The selected columns don't fit visually into my window, that means, they have the same width than my table with all the columns, even if the result is only one column. They are also kind of offset.. I created an example here:

```js
$('.data-table').DataTable({
  "scrollX": true,
  initComplete: function () {
    $('<div style="float:right;min-width:200px"><div style="float:right;"><select name="productgroup" class="productgroup form-control select2" style="width: 100%;"><option value="all">All</option><option value="name">Name</option><option value="position">Position</option><option value="office">Office</option><option value="age">Age</option><option value="startdate">Startdate</option><option value="salary">Salary</option></select></div><div style="float:right;margin:4px 10px 10px">Filter</div></div>').appendTo($("#DataTables_Table_0_filter"));
    $("select").on("change", function () {
      var product = $(this).val();
      $(".all").hide();
      $("." + product).show();
    });
  }
});
```

```css
div.dataTables_wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://almsaeedstudio.com/themes/AdminLTE/plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.css">

<script src="https://almsaeedstudio.com/themes/AdminLTE/plugins/jQuery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://almsaeedstudio.com/themes/AdminLTE/plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<table class="data-table table table-bordered table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="all name">Name</th>
      <th class="all position">Position 1</th>
      <th class="all position">Position 2</th>
      <th class="all">Age</th>
      <th class="all">Start date</th>
      <th class="all">Salary</th>
      <th class="all">Name</th>
      <th class="all">Something</th>
      <th class="all">Something</th>
      <th class="all">Age</th>
      <th class="all">Start date</th>
      <th class="all">Salary</th>
      <th class="all">Name</th>
      <th class="all">Something</th>
      <th class="all">Something</th>
      <th class="all">Age</th>
      <th class="all">Start date</th>
      <th class="all">Salary</th>
      <th class="all">Something</th>
      <th class="all">Something</th>
      <th class="all">Something else</th>
      <th class="all">Age</th>
      <th class="all">Start date</th>
      <th class="all">Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="all name">Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td class="all position">System Architect</td>
      <td class="all position">Edinburgh</td>
      <td class="all">61</td>
      <td class="all">2011/04/25</td>
      <td class="all">$320,800</td>
      <td class="all">Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td class="all">System Architect</td>
      <td class="all">Edinburgh</td>
      <td class="all">61</td>
      <td class="all">2011/04/25</td>
      <td class="all">$320,800</td>
      <td class="all">Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td class="all">System Architect</td>
      <td class="all">Edinburgh</td>
      <td class="all">61</td>
      <td class="all">2011/04/25</td>
      <td class="all">$320,800</td>
      <td class="all">Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td class="all">System Architect</td>
      <td class="all">Edinburgh</td>
      <td class="all">61</td>
      <td class="all">2011/04/25</td>
      <td class="all">$320,800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="all name">Garrett Winters</td>
      <td class="all position">Accountant</td>
      <td class="all position">Tokyo</td>
      <td class="all">63</td>
      <td class="all">2011/07/25</td>
      <td class="all">$170,750</td>
      <td class="all">Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td class="all">System Architect</td>
      <td class="all">Edinburgh</td>
      <td class="all">61</td>
      <td class="all">2011/04/25</td>
      <td class="all">$320,800</td>
      <td class="all">Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td class="all">System Architect</td>
      <td class="all">Edinburgh</td>
      <td class="all">61</td>
      <td class="all">2011/04/25</td>
      <td class="all">$320,800</td>
      <td class="all">Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td class="all">System Architect</td>
      <td class="all">Edinburgh</td>
      <td class="all">61</td>
      <td class="all">2011/04/25</td>
      <td class="all">$320,800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="all name">Ashton Cox</td>
      <td class="all position">Junior Technical Author</td>
      <td class="all position">San Francisco</td>
      <td class="all">66</td>
      <td class="all">2009/01/12</td>
      <td class="all">$86,000</td>
      <td class="all">Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td class="all">System Architect</td>
      <td class="all">Edinburgh</td>
      <td class="all">61</td>
      <td class="all">2011/04/25</td>
      <td class="all">$320,800</td>
      <td class="all">Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td class="all">System Architect</td>
      <td class="all">Edinburgh</td>
      <td class="all">61</td>
      <td class="all">2011/04/25</td>
      <td class="all">$320,800</td>
      <td class="all">Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td class="all">System Architect</td>
      <td class="all">Edinburgh</td>
      <td class="all">Edinburgh</td>
      <td class="all">Edinburgh</td>
      <td class="all">61</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lot of bad practice in your code. Let me point out them

- You have class names in all the `td` elements in the `tbody`- **Classes to the header is sufficient.** (you will see why in my below code)
- You are appending the dropdown to the table in the `initComplete` callback to a `element` that is dynamically created by the plugin `('#DataTables_Table_0_filter')`, which is not the recommended approach by the plugin author. - **If you want to manipulate the Table UI you must use the plugin provided [dom](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) option**.
- You are manually hiding all the headers and the `td` cells in the body for the change event. This will again have issues when you page, change disply length as the plugin is not aware of this change and it will redraw the table as per its previous configuration - **You need to manipulate the table by using the plugin provided methods.** **[column.visible( )](https://datatables.net/examples/api/show_hide.html)** ,The parameters that can be passed into the **[columns() api details](https://datatables.net/reference/type/column-selector)**
- Also there is a bug in your code already which you can see if you change the display length - Again this is because of the way you are using the plugin. (below example fixes it)

So given these information, I have changed your code to the best possible way.

```js
var yourTableObj = $('.data-table').DataTable({
 "dom": "<'row'<'col-sm-4'l><'col-sm-4'f><'col-sm-4 customFilterHolder'>>" +
 "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
 "<'row'<'col-sm-5'i><'col-sm-7'p>>",
 "scrollX": true,    
  initComplete: function(){
      $(".customFilterHolder").html('<div style="float:right;min-width:200px"><div style="float:right;"><select name="productgroup" class="productgroup form-control select2" style="width: 100%;"><option value="all">All</option><option value="name">Name</option><option value="position">Position</option><option value="office">Office</option><option value="age">Age</option><option value="startdate">Startdate</option><option value="salary">Salary</option></select></div><div style="float:right;margin:4px 10px 10px">Filter</div></div>');      

      $('.productgroup').on('change',function(){
          yourTableObj.columns().visible(true); //reset table to show all columns
          yourTableObj.columns(':not(.'+$(this).val()+')').visible(false);  // now hide unwanted columns.
         // the reset is important because if you dont the table will work the present state of the table. 
      });    
   }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://almsaeedstudio.com/themes/AdminLTE/plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.css">

<script src="https://almsaeedstudio.com/themes/AdminLTE/plugins/jQuery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://almsaeedstudio.com/themes/AdminLTE/plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<table class="data-table table table-bordered table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="all name">Name</th>
      <th class="all position">Position 1</th>
      <th class="all position">Position 2</th>
      <th class="all">Age</th>
      <th class="all">Start date</th>
      <th class="all">Salary</th>
      <th class="all">Name</th>
      <th class="all">Something</th>
      <th class="all">Something</th>
      <th class="all">Age</th>
      <th class="all">Start date</th>
      <th class="all">Salary</th>
      <th class="all">Name</th>
      <th class="all">Something</th>
      <th class="all">Something</th>
      <th class="all">Age</th>
      <th class="all">Start date</th>
      <th class="all">Salary</th>
      <th class="all">Something</th>
      <th class="all">Something</th>
      <th class="all">Something else</th>
      <th class="all">Age</th>
      <th class="all">Start date</th>
      <th class="all">Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Garrett Winters</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>63</td>
      <td>2011/07/25</td>
      <td>$170,750</td>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ashton Cox</td>
      <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>66</td>
      <td>2009/01/12</td>
      <td>$86,000</td>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful!

Comment: @Jarla Glad to help.. Also there is a bug in your current code, you can see it if you change the display length of the table.. with the approach suggested in this answer you should be able to fix it..

Comment: There is a little bug/issue appearing, while working with your code. Everything works very well so far. But if I add a language parameter `"language": {"url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/German.json",},` to  `var yourTableObj` my filter is gone. Do you have an idea why this is happening. I am just asking, because this has worked with my code.

Comment: @Jarla Looks like we need to wait untill the plugin is complete initializing with all the options and then append the filter.. I have updated the code and points to reflect the same.. have a check.. sorry for not looking into this earlier

Comment: Thank you! I saw your update. Like this the filter is visible and the language is also working. I only had to move `$('.productgroup').on('change',function` into `initComplete: function()` to make the select box work. (in my code it was not working otherwise, I do not know why, because I see it does in your example, have to figure it out..)

Comment: Thank you very much! Now everything is working beautifully

Comment: @Jarla Happy coding!!! Also remember always when you are using any plugin it will have inbuilt methods to support all your requirements, So spare some time to look into the documentation and use the plugin provided methods.. this is safer as it will not result in bugs.. in very rare cases we would have to do a work around.. but that's very rare..

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`columns.adjust()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/columns.adjust()) though I'm not sure if this is the desired result but it does adjust the columns accordingly.

```js
$('.data-table').DataTable({
  "scrollX": true,
  initComplete: function(settings) {
    $('<div style="float:right;min-width:200px"><div style="float:right;"><select name="productgroup" class="productgroup form-control select2" style="width: 100%;"><option value="all">All</option><option value="name">Name</option><option value="position">Position</option><option value="office">Office</option><option value="age">Age</option><option value="startdate">Startdate</option><option value="salary">Salary</option></select></div><div style="float:right;margin:4px 10px 10px">Filter</div></div>').appendTo($("#DataTables_Table_0_filter"));
    $("select").on("change", function() {
      var product = $(this).val();
      $(".all").hide();
      $("." + product).show();
      var api = new $.fn.dataTable.Api(settings);
      api.columns.adjust().draw();
    });

  }
});
```

```css
div.dataTables_wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://almsaeedstudio.com/themes/AdminLTE/plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.css">

<script src="https://almsaeedstudio.com/themes/AdminLTE/plugins/jQuery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://almsaeedstudio.com/themes/AdminLTE/plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<table class="data-table table table-bordered table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="all name">Name</th>
      <th class="all position">Position 1</th>
      <th class="all position">Position 2</th>
      <th class="all">Age</th>
      <th class="all">Start date</th>
      <th class="all">Salary</th>
      <th class="all">Name</th>
      <th class="all">Something</th>
      <th class="all">Something</th>
      <th class="all">Age</th>
      <th class="all">Start date</th>
      <th class="all">Salary</th>
      <th class="all">Name</th>
      <th class="all">Something</th>
      <th class="all">Something</th>
      <th class="all">Age</th>
      <th class="all">Start date</th>
      <th class="all">Salary</th>
      <th class="all">Something</th>
      <th class="all">Something</th>
      <th class="all">Something else</th>
      <th class="all">Age</th>
      <th class="all">Start date</th>
      <th class="all">Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="all name">Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td class="all position">System Architect</td>
      <td class="all position">Edinburgh</td>
      <td class="all">61</td>
      <td class="all">2011/04/25</td>
      <td class="all">$320,800</td>
      <td class="all">Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td class="all">System Architect</td>
      <td class="all">Edinburgh</td>
      <td class="all">61</td>
      <td class="all">2011/04/25</td>
      <td class="all">$320,800</td>
      <td class="all">Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td class="all">System Architect</td>
      <td class="all">Edinburgh</td>
      <td class="all">61</td>
      <td class="all">2011/04/25</td>
      <td class="all">$320,800</td>
      <td class="all">Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td class="all">System Architect</td>
      <td class="all">Edinburgh</td>
      <td class="all">61</td>
      <td class="all">2011/04/25</td>
      <td class="all">$320,800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="all name">Garrett Winters</td>
      <td class="all position">Accountant</td>
      <td class="all position">Tokyo</td>
      <td class="all">63</td>
      <td class="all">2011/07/25</td>
      <td class="all">$170,750</td>
      <td class="all">Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td class="all">System Architect</td>
      <td class="all">Edinburgh</td>
      <td class="all">61</td>
      <td class="all">2011/04/25</td>
      <td class="all">$320,800</td>
      <td class="all">Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td class="all">System Architect</td>
      <td class="all">Edinburgh</td>
      <td class="all">61</td>
      <td class="all">2011/04/25</td>
      <td class="all">$320,800</td>
      <td class="all">Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td class="all">System Architect</td>
      <td class="all">Edinburgh</td>
      <td class="all">61</td>
      <td class="all">2011/04/25</td>
      <td class="all">$320,800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="all name">Ashton Cox</td>
      <td class="all position">Junior Technical Author</td>
      <td class="all position">San Francisco</td>
      <td class="all">66</td>
      <td class="all">2009/01/12</td>
      <td class="all">$86,000</td>
      <td class="all">Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td class="all">System Architect</td>
      <td class="all">Edinburgh</td>
      <td class="all">61</td>
      <td class="all">2011/04/25</td>
      <td class="all">$320,800</td>
      <td class="all">Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td class="all">System Architect</td>
      <td class="all">Edinburgh</td>
      <td class="all">61</td>
      <td class="all">2011/04/25</td>
      <td class="all">$320,800</td>
      <td class="all">Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td class="all">System Architect</td>
      <td class="all">Edinburgh</td>
      <td class="all">Edinburgh</td>
      <td class="all">Edinburgh</td>
      <td class="all">61</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```